# Vaadin 14 Grid do not show all rows

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid

we have V14 apps and grid with simple rows output from Java object. When grid value is set (Grid.setItems(...)) we put arraylist with 8 rows. But on the screen we see only first 5 rows. We have log arraylist and it has 8 items. We don't know how to start debug this problem to find where the issue is. Some ideas :

1. app is running on low-budget Windows tablet, specialized for warehouses. But it is using chrome browser. In code we are using grid.setHeightByRows(true). Is it possible this value is not calculate right?
2. our Java object is Lombok objekt with @Data annotation.

Any idea in which direction we should debug this problem? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: My first thougth is the `equals` function of your Grid items. The grid will not show multiple rows for items that are considered "equal". Make sure that none of your desired items are equal to each other.

Comment: Thank you for tip. But our JavaBean is POJO object with Lombok @Data annotation. This annotation use "Generates hashCode and equals implementations from the fields of your object", so equals method should return different values.

Comment: You are oddly specific about the tablet with Chrome. Does this imply, that the
problem is _only_ with that OS/browser -- or is this irrelevant and other
OS/browser show the same problem?  For debugging hits: what rows are missing?
Do they have anything in common?  If you remove rows, is it still the first five...

Comment: Like @kscherrer, my guess is that the issue has to do with `equals` implementation. You say that Lombok @Data generates equals from the fields, so my dumb question is: are you sure that the fields' values are not equal for some of your POJOs?

Comment: Agree with the above. Lombok @Data is likely the culprit here. To rule this out, implement proper `hashCode` and `equals` (pay extra attention that you're not making two objects with the same data equal)

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Unfortunately, we can't repeat this error on a computer web browser. It is only Windows tablet. 
In POJO object we have "id" field which is unique because this is a value from DB sequence.

Comment: POJOs used in Grid should rely only in the id as identity. So if you change a value of one of the properties, that will not affect identity, equals would still return true. Thus Lombok autogenerated hashCode and equals should not be used in POJOs used in Vaadin Grid.